# Speed up nested loop to manipulate each value of nested list

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a nested list generated from converting a numpy matrix to list:

```
[
    [0.65, 0.66, 4.29, 2.91, 0.17, 3.92, 2.24, 0.56, 8.99, 0.34, 0.0],
    [0.012, 0.038, 0.072, 0.236, 0.012, 0.258, 0.075, 0.003, 0.0, 0.002, 0.0], 
    [0.003, 0.039, 0.138, 0.02, 0.002, 0.32, 0.013, 0.001, 0.999, 0.0, 0.0], 
    [0.154, 0.043, 0.737, 0.475, 0.028, 0.002, 0.485, 0.145, 0.0, 0.035, 0.0], 
    [0.018, 0.0, 0.019, 0.175, 0.01, 0.0, 0.065, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0801, 0.0, 0.6707, 0.1496, 0.0112, 0.0, 0.2668, 0.0798, 0.0, 0.0385, 0.0],
    [118.0, 88.0, 120.0, 186.0, 220.0, 146.0, 157.0, 150.0, 50.0, 50.0, 0.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
]
```

I'm currently looping through each element to do the following operation:

```
A1 = A.tolist()

for index, v in enumerate(A1):
    for index2, v2 in enumerate(v):
        A1[index][index2] = float(v2 + offsets[index]) / norms[index] * priorita[index]

 A1 = np.matrix(A1)
```

Because this operation is executed more than 3.000.000 times, it's the bottleneck of my application.

1. Is there any native method of numpy that could help me with performances?
2. Could something like replacing enumerate with map help me with performances?

Please provide examples and links to docs.

Thanks.

Comment: Curious: why did you make this into a list? Leaving it as a NumPy array will allow you to use vectorized operations, and all the same indexing will still work.

Comment: Otherwise I get the following error: TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: You should try to figure out why that code isn't working, then. It is definitely not worth converting to Python lists to do calculation, especially if you will just convert back to an array afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the same result under the assumptions below.

```
A1 = (A1+offsets)*(priorita/norms)
```

Assumptions:

1. `A1`: n*m matrix
2. `offsets`: n*1 vector
3. `norms`: n*1 vector
4. `priorita`: n*1 vector
5. These are all `numpy.array`

Comment: All the assumptions are correct. In my test case n = 18 and m = 11. I used `A1 = (A + offsets) * (priorita / norms)` but I'm getting ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (18,11) (18)

Comment: everything has to be converted to `numpy.ndarray` format. For example, if you do `norms.shape`, you should get `(18,1)`.

Comment: Great, now offsets.shape, norm.shapes and priorita.shape are all returning (18, 1) and A1.shape is returning (18, 11). However I'm now getting `ValueError: matrices are not aligned` at the line containing `A1 =  (A1 + offsets) * (priorita / norms)`

Comment: are you sure they all return `(18,1)` `(18,11)` and so on? If one of them has shape `(18,)` then it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I'm printing it and it's (18,1) for norms, priorita and offsets and (18,11) for A1. The error is occurring exactly in the multiplication. The sum and division in parenthesis are working fine, but the multiplication is returning `ValueError: matrices are not aligned`

Comment: I've been able to do the same operation by using `np.multiply((A1 + offsets) / norms , priorita)`. Thanks a lot for pointing me the right direction